# Getting 'this.editAction not a function exception' when passing as promise to grand child component in angular(4)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I have parent component which passes a promise to grand child component.

I am facing some weird this is not a function when calling that method from parent to grand child.
I am sending the function within the promise exactly as it is supposed to. I am using angular 4.

I pass in the event emitter form Grand Child to Child, and then again pass the save event emitter from child to parent. This is @Output event emitter when edit is clicked on child.

When this is clicked in child, I then trigger a method in the parent to pass a method from parent as a promise to the the grandchild which should be implemented/called in grandchild.

When the child receives data from the grand child, the input field is disabled (at first). But when I click on edit in the grand child. I emit a method to the parent via child. This is for the parent to do everything (data manipulation).

But when I try to send the data as a function via promise to grand child, it says that the method name editAction is not a function (which is a promise).

This is weird as I am passing the func from parent.(see at the bottom of the code).

```
//Grand Child TS (code)
@Component({
selector: 'grand-child',
templateUrl: './grand-child.component.html',
})
export class GrandChild {
@Input()
public item: TrackingObj;//this is an interface where all the variable are set for tracking
@Input()
public editAction: (TrackingObj) => Promise<boolean> = (record) => Promise.resolve(true);
@Output()
public editClicked: EventEmitter<TrackingObj> = new EventEmitter();

edit(){
 this.editClicked.emit(this.item);
this.editAction(this.item).then(result => {
    If(result.editMode)
     result.editMode = false
    Else 
     result.editMode = true;
});
}

}

//Grand Child HTML Component
<div>
<a
 id="btn-edit"
(click)="edit()"
>
<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
</a>
</div>

//Child Component TS Code
@Component({
    selector: 'parameter-values-list',
    templateUrl: './child.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss']
})
export class ParameterValuesListComponent implements OnInit {
@Input()
public editItemData: (TrackingObj) => Promise<boolean> = (record) => Promise.resolve(true);
@Output()
public editClick:  EventEmitter<TrackingObj> = new EventEmitter();
Private item: TrackingObj;

editClickInChild(item: TrackingObj) {
 this.editClick.emit(item);
}
}


//Child HTML Component
<div>
<input
Value=""
[disabled]="item.editMode"
/>
<grand-child [editAction]="editItemData" (editClicked)="editClickInChild(item)"></grand-child>
</div>


//Parent Component TS Code
@Component({
selector: 'parent',
templateUrl: './parent.component.html'
})
Export class Parent {
Private item: TrackingObj;
Private editItemToChild: (TrackingObj) => Promise<boolean> = (item) => new Promise(resolve => resolve(true))

editItemClick(form: AbstractControl): (TrackingObj) => Promise<boolean> {
        let func = (item: LpiParameterValue) => {

//if item has child element do something            
if (item.hasChildren) {
        //do something                
            }

            return new Promise(resolve => {
                resolve(item);
            });
        };

        return func.bind(this);
    }

editClickedInParent(item: TrackingObj) {
//do something here
 this.editItemToChild = editItemClick(); 
}
}


//Parent Html Code
<div>
<child [editItemData]="editItemToChild" (editClick)="editClickedInParent(item)"></child>
</div>
```

Comment: why would you `bind` `this` to an arrow function? Also, the way you're using promises is convoluted

Comment: convoluted?? can you point where I need to change that promise usage?? Since I am waiting for the promise to reach child after I click the edit button in child, if i set a timeout in the child component, I can see that the editAction is working. Is there anything that I can change and this way of implementation works?

Comment: it is convoluted because it's almost never appropriate to directly create a promise using `new` unless you are adapting an existing API.  this almost certainly indicates a misunderstanding of promises